# find -exec cmd {} + vs | xargs

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, find

Which one is more efficient over a very large set of files and should be used?

```
find . -exec cmd {} +
```

or

```
find . | xargs cmd
```

(Assume that there are no funny characters in the filenames)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612090/how-to-loop-through-file-names-returned-by-find

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Speed difference will be insignificant.

But you have to make sure that:

1. Your script will not assume that no
   file will have space, tab, etc in
   file name; the first version is
   safe, the second is not.
2. Your script will not treat a file starting with "`-`" as an option.

So your code should look like this:

```
find . -exec cmd -option1 -option2 -- {} +
```

or

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 cmd -option1 -option2 --
```

The first version is shorter and easier to write as you can ignore 1, but 
the second version is more portable and safe, as "`-exec cmd {} +`" is a relatively new option in GNU findutils (since 2005, lots of running systems will not have it yet) and it was [buggy recently](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=16738). Also lots of people do not know this "`-exec cmd {} +`", as you can see from other answers.

Comment: -print0 is also a GNU find (and GNU xargs) option which is missing from a lot of non-Linux systems, so the portability argument isn't as valid.  Using just -print and leaving the -0 off of xargs, however, *is* very portable.

Comment: The point is that without -print0 it does not work if there is a file with a space or tab etc. This can be a security vulnerability as if there is a filename like "foo -o index.html" then -o will be treated as an option. Try in empty directory: "touch -- foo\ -o\ index.html; find . | xargs cat". You'll get: "cat: invalid option -- 'o'"

Comment: His example is a filename that contains a -. Without -print0, find will spit out ./foo -o index.html. So maybe starting with a - isn't a big deal, but the result is little changed, and on a multiuser system, could provide an attack vector if your script is world readable.

Comment: A note on something which tripped me up here - using `exec` will output results as they are found, wheras `xargs` will, it seems, wait until the entire directory is searched before writing to stdout. If you're trying this on a large directory, and it seems that `xargs` isn't working, patience is advisable.

Comment: Regarding '--':
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147143/when-and-how-was-the-double-dash-introduced-as-an-end-of-options-delimiter

Comment: Since `find` always outputs filenames with a path (e.g. `./file`) I don't see why `--` would be needed in this case. It's true though that because of possible newline characters the zero-delimiter settings are necessary.

Comment: @phk - What do you mean by `zero-delimiter settings`?

Comment: @Tometzky - Do you mean to say that i would have to run the command `find . -exec cmd -- {} +` to avoid expanding `-` as an option? If i am unaware that there are files that precede with `-` e.g. `-file1.txt`, the answer seems to suggests that i would need to use `-- {}`.

Comment: @Tometzky - What is the purpose of `-0` in the command `xargs -0`?

Comment: @bobpaul - What do you mean by it could provide an attack vector?

Comment: @Motivated files on most unices can have any byte in name (a tab, a horozontal tab, space, minus, quote etc). The only byte which isn't allowed is byte `0`. The `-print0` option for find and `-0` for xargs forces filesnames to be separated with byte 0. You're right about `--`, although modern GNU find never produces filenames starting with `-` it a good idea in general to separate options and arguments in case find will be replaced with some other program.

Comment: @Tometzky - Thanks. What do you mean by "forces file names to be separated with a byte 0? Why is `-print0` not used with the first `find` command? To clarify the use of `--`, do you mean to say that it's always best to include it in the command?

Comment: @Motivated Without `-print0` find returns filenames separated with newline, but newline can also be part of a filename, making it ambiguous. Byte 0 can't, so it is a safe separator. Yes - adding `--` to a command that supports it is a good practice when you can't control its arguments, even if not always strictly required or unsafe.

Comment: @Tometzky - Thanks. Do you mean to say that if i use the command find . -exec echo {} + without the use of --print0 or -- it would result in filenames separated by newlines as well as filesnames that begin with -?

Comment: @Tometzky - To minimize the number of comments, it would be great if you can join (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89297/find-exec-xargs)

Comment: @Motivated I'm pretty sure back in 2012 when I commented there was another comment between @tometzky's comment and my own. the -- in the example should be generally safe, but tricky filenames can still cause unexpected behavior. Here's a pastebin showing where things can go wrong without using `-print0`: https://pastebin.com/3irfB3tW

Answer (score 9):

```
find . | xargs cmd
```

is more efficient (it runs `cmd` as few times as possible, unlike `exec`, which runs `cmd` once for each match). However, you will run into trouble if filenames contain spaces or funky characters.

The following is suggested to be used:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 cmd
```

this will work even if filenames contain funky characters (`-print0` makes `find` print NUL-terminated matches, `-0` makes `xargs` expect this format.)

Comment: This is not
"find . -exec cmd {} \;"
but
"find . -exec cmd {} +". The latter will not run one file at a time.

Comment: Note that the `xargs` approach is actually significantly slower if there are no (or only a few) matching files and `cmd` doesn't have much to do for each file.  For example, when run in an empty directory, the `xargs` version will take at least twice the time, since two processes must be started instead of just one.  (Yes, the difference is usually imperceptible on *nix, but in a loop it could be important; or, try it on Windows some time ...)

Answer (score 3):

Modern `xargs`'s versions often support parallel pipeline execution.

Obviously it might be a pivot point when it comes to choice between
`find … -exec`
and
`… | xargs`