# how to pipe output from find to pdf viewer

Tags: linux, bash, pdf, find, bash-function

Hello Bash Superheros,

I am trying to create a simple bash function that pipes the output from **find** to a a pdf viewer, similar but limited to **evince**.

```
function findpapers {
    find ~/papers/ -name *$1* | evince 
}
```

The above function opens the viewer but does not display any of the desired files/paths.  Ultimately, I would like to display all the pdf's outputted from **find**.  A simple find command such as:

```
$ find /home/alex/papers/ -name *erebus*
```

creates an output like:

```
/home/alex/papers/2000/rowe/seismic_and_acoustic_observations_at_mount_erebus_volcano_ross_island_antarctica.pdf

/home/alex/papers/2008/Jones/infrasonic_tracking_of_large_bubble_bursts_and_ash_venting_at_erebus_volcano_antarctica.pdf
```

Then the idea is to display those two pdf files in a viewer.

Any ideas or suggestions?  I am using Linux Mint if that helps.  Thanks heaps in advance!

Comment: The simple way is to use xargs. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896808/find-exec-cmd-vs-xargs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the list of file names on the command line of evince, not in its standard input.

Use

```
evince $(find /home/alex/papers/ -name *erebus*)
```

or

```
find /home/alex/papers/ -name *erebus* | xargs evince
```

On linux (or any OS that uses the gnu versions of find and xargs) , if there is any chance the file names might contain spaces, better use

```
find /home/alex/papers/ -name *erebus* -print0 | xargs -0 evince
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to use

```
find /home/alex/papers/ -iname '*erebus*' -exec evince '{}' +
```

- iname tells find that the search pattern given is case insensitive.
- -exec executes the given command evince with the found filenames inserted for {}. The plus sign tells find to append all found filenames to a single evince command, instead of starting a new evince for each single found file. If you replace + with an escaped semicolon (\;), you get the latter behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bash` 4 or later, you don't need `find`:

```
shopt -s globstar
evince /home/alex/papers/**/*erebus*
```